# using subfig changes fonts in captions of figures

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, ieeeconf

I used package subfig(for using \subfloat). This undoes the special font size for the captions in the figures. Now they are of same size as normal text. How to counter that?

The Document class and packages included are:

```
documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf} 


\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              
\overrideIEEEmargins
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfig, graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .jpeg, .png, .jpg}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
```

The figure I added is:

```
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,height=0.3\textwidth]
{images/framework.eps}
\caption{Block diagrammic representation of our framework}
\label{fig:framework}
\end{figure}
```

I am able to see small font if I remove subfig.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: edited with example.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`; the `caption` package loaded by default is not compatible with IEEE classes.

Comment: thanks it worked , please add this as answer. Can't I use subfigure and subfig together? It seems to create conflict...

Comment: No, you can use only one, either `subfigure` or `subfig'.

Comment: @egreg Please add your response as answer. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package `caption` is not compatible with the IEEE classes; you can still load `subfig`, but with

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

which won't redefine the `\caption` command, but will provide the main functionalities of `subfig` nonetheless.